# MongoDB join on nested Array

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently working on a small chat roulette application. For that I user MongoDB and NodeJS in the Backend. To list all of the chat channel I want to join two collections. The elements of the first one (chats) has nested arrays:

```
{
  title: 'example 1',
  country: 'UK',
  ...
  chat: [
    {
      details: 'chat1 infos',
      channel: [
        '5ea3257d4b861a5aa0d03111',
        '5ea3257d4b861a5aa0d03122'
      ]
    },
    {
      details: 'chat2 infos',
      channel: [
        '5ea3257d4b861a5aa0d03333'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The second one (channels) stores all the details:

```
{
  _id: '5ea3257d4b861a5aa0d03111',
  title: 'Channel1',
  details: 'Channel1 Details'
},
{
  _id: '5ea3257d4b861a5aa0d03222',
  title: 'Channel2',
  details: 'Channel2 Details'
},
{
  _id: '5ea3257d4b861a5aa0d03333',
  title: 'Channel3',
  details: 'Channel13 Details'
}
```

The result should look like that:

```
{
  title: 'example 1',
  country: 'UK',
  ...
  chat: [
    {
      details: 'chat1 infos',
      channel: [
        {
          _id: '5ea3257d4b861a5aa0d03111',
          title: 'Channel1',
          details: 'Channel1 Details'
        },
        {
          _id: '5ea3257d4b861a5aa0d03222',
          title: 'Channel2',
          details: 'Channel2 Details'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      details: 'chat2 infos',
      channel: [
        {
          _id: '5ea3257d4b861a5aa0d03333',
          title: 'Channel3',
          details: 'Channel13 Details'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried that by using $lookup:

```
db.collection('chats').aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "channel",
    "localField": "chat.channel",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "chat.channel"
  } }
]);
```

But by that, I join all results on each channel. 
Regardless of which ids are contained in the channel. How I can join the collections to get the described result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
db.chats.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$chat" // we need this as we have an array of chats, and each chat element has an array of channels
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "channels", // will use pipeline in lookup to get rid of multiple group stages
      let: {
        channelIds: "$chat.channel"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id", // _id of channel
                "$$channelIds" // channel ids from chat.channel array
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "chat.channel"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id", // group the unwinded chat array
      title: {
        $first: "$title"
      },
      country: {
        $first: "$country"
      },
      chat: {
        $push: "$chat"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

check this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/weOkVaPBVLd)

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this section**

> you can use populate

```
 let _doc =await firstModel.find().populate("channels")
```

Comment: I'm not using mongoose